# Cannot catch the exception through @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler in CRUD application

Tags: java, rest, exception, post

I am trying to create custom exceptionhandler but it is not catching my exception (UserAlreadyExistsException; UserNotFoundException is working very well). I`ve read another questions but these advices did not help me out.
My controller advice class is the following:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class UserExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    private ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> handleCommonHelper(final Exception exception, final HttpStatus status) {
        final var errorDto = new ErrorDTO();
        errorDto.setCode(String.valueOf(status.value()));
        errorDto.setErrorDetails(exception.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(errorDto, status);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {UserNotFoundException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> handleUserNameNotFoundConflict(final UserNotFoundException e) {
        return this.handleCommonHelper(e, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {UserAlreadyExistsException.class})
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> handleUserNameExistsConflict(final UserAlreadyExistsException e) {
        return this.handleCommonHelper(e, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

My method `create` looks like the following:

```
 @Override
public UserDTO createUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
    var databaseUser = userRepository.existsById(Long.valueOf(userDTO.getUsername()));
    if (databaseUser) {
        throw new UserAlreadyExistsException("User with this username already exists!");
    }
    userDTO.setId(null);
    var userEntity = mapToUserEntity(userDTO);
    return mapToUserDTO(userRepository.save(userEntity));
}
```

And my controller:

```
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "Created")
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Client error"),
        @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Server error")
})
@Operation(summary = "Creation of user", description = "Creation of user")
@PostMapping("/users")
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> createUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO) {
    var createdUser = userService.createUser(userDTO);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(createdUser, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Well, now I can create several users with the same username and get 201 code.
Could you give me the piece of advice - how can I catch this exception?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like there is an error in logic:
It is seems to me that `databaseUser` is always false.

```
var databaseUser = userRepository.existsById(Long.valueOf(userDTO.getUsername()));
    if (databaseUser) {
```

You try to get user from database by Id, but you are using username.
Looks like it should be smth like this:

```
var databaseUser = userRepository.existsByUsername(userDTO.getUsername());
```

You have to check user for existing by unique for user fields (if in your system username is unique, you have to check by username)